# Media Player is playing get confused to catch Custom Next Intent

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm made simple `Media Player` by using `MediaResponse`.

Google automatically handle : `play`, `pause`, `stop`, `resume`.

Since Google not supported : `next` function yet, I created `custom Next Intent` to handle `next` function.

I had 2 cases makes me confused after `talk to Dr. Media` then `go` :

`MediaResponse` show correctly, **not playing yet (not click button Play yet).**

**Case 1** - Then I say `next` (or `next song`), it **matched with my defined phrases** in my custom intent. And `Next function` is OK.

**Case 2** - I **clicked Play button to play audio**, then I say `next` (or `next song`), it **didn't match with my defined phrases** (it oftens say `Okay` and nothing happens), so `Next function` is not OK. (As images in below)

[image]
[image]

In case 2, How I can catch my phrases `next`, `next song`, `play next` ... when Media Player is playing? (*In other words, these phrases can not trigger my custom intent*)

Please help me, Thanks

*p/s : It happens on Mobile phones*

`actions_intent_NEXT.json`

```
    {
  "id": "01055a59-26a0-4f39-a770-6bc5404482d9",
  "name": "actions_intent_NEXT",
  "auto": true,
  "contexts": [
    "actions_capability_screen_output",
    "actions_capability_media_response_audio"
  ],
  "responses": [
    {
      "resetContexts": false,
      "affectedContexts": [
        {
          "name": "actions_capability_screen_output",
          "parameters": {},
          "lifespan": 5
        },
        {
          "name": "actions_capability_media_response_audio",
          "parameters": {},
          "lifespan": 5
        }
      ],
      "parameters": [
        {
          "id": "2ce8514c-a346-4251-9a35-cab32d2c9d7c",
          "required": false,
          "dataType": "@nextPlay",
          "name": "nextPlay",
          "value": "$nextPlay",
          "isList": false
        }
      ],
      "messages": [
        {
          "type": 0,
          "speech": []
        }
      ],
      "defaultResponsePlatforms": {},
      "speech": []
    }
  ],
  "priority": 500000,
  "cortanaCommand": {
    "navigateOrService": "NAVIGATE",
    "target": ""
  },
  "webhookUsed": true,
  "webhookForSlotFilling": false,
  "lastUpdate": 1542252675,
  "fallbackIntent": false,
  "events": [
    {
      "name": "actions_intent_NEXT"
    }
  ],
  "userSays": [
    {
      "id": "e28a4087-2bf9-494d-9790-c7347f870ee4",
      "data": [
        {
          "text": "next song",
          "alias": "nextPlay",
          "meta": "@nextPlay",
          "userDefined": true
        }
      ],
      "isTemplate": false,
      "count": 0,
      "updated": 1542249008,
      "isAuto": false
    },
    {
      "id": "7a8cf2a2-d131-490d-977d-1212f4642f52",
      "data": [
        {
          "text": "next",
          "alias": "nextPlay",
          "meta": "@nextPlay",
          "userDefined": true
        }
      ],
      "isTemplate": false,
      "count": 0,
      "updated": 1542248700,
      "isAuto": false
    }
  ],
  "followUpIntents": [],
  "liveAgentHandoff": false,
  "endInteraction": false,
  "templates": []
   }
```

Comment: Catching these events during playback is currently not supported. You can file a feature request: https://developers.google.com/actions/support/